# How to access to the content of a DataRow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have the following problem.

I have a **DataTAble** object that represent a single column table, the column is named **VulnerabilityReferenceId**, something like this:

```
VulnerabilityReferenceId
167554
167555
167556
167557
167558
167559
167560
167561
```

So I want create a foreach that access to these row and put the value into a variable

I have done:

```
foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("VulnerabilityReferenceId: "  );
}
```

But what can I do to access to the value of the current row and put it into an int variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be an approach that read the field and convert it to the required datatype.
It requires the reference to DataSetExtension assembly from NET3.5 where you could start to find the [DataRowExtensions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
{
    int id = row.Field<int>("VulnerabilityReferenceId");
    .....
}
```

Note: I assume that the field `VulnerabilityReferenceId` is of type integer

Answer (score 1):

You can use column name as an indexer to get the value as `object`

```
foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
{
    int vulRefId=Convert.ToInt32(row["VulnerabilityReferenceId"]);
    Debug.WriteLine("VulnerabilityReferenceId: " +vulRefId  );
}
```

Comment: `_dt.Rows[rowindex][columnname]`. The first indexer is the index of the row not the name of the column. Probably you want to write `row["VulnerabilityReferenceId"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
for(int i=0;i<_dt.Rows.Count;i++)
 {
   Debug.WriteLine("VulnerabilityReferenceId: "+dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
{
    String stringVal = row["VulnerabilityReferenceId"].ToString();
    int myId = Convert.ToInt32(stringVal);
}
```